# Apart from <HR/> Is there any other options for drawing line in Bootstrap3?

Tags: html, css

I found `<HR/>` tag in BootStrap3 is having much margin. I am developing page which has compact look during this `<HR/>` is not looking good on my page. Can you have any other options which allows me to draw a line in Bootstrap 3 ? Or how to remove margin of `<HR/>` tag of BootStrap3.

Answer (score 4):

Surely you have custom CSS for your project. Add a bit more:

```
hr.my-class {margin: 0;}

<hr class="my-class" />
```

Or simply:

```
hr {margin: 0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for "another way" to draw a line.  Often, I've used a bottom border for a tag as a sort of underline/divider, e.g.

```
.underline {
    border:solid #CCC;border-width:0 0 1px 0;
}
```

You could drop this into a heading tag, into your .row, or whatever and get an underline that will not take up any space other than the height of the line itself.

Comment: Or simply `border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc`. You may also need to add `padding-bottom` for a nicer appearance.